# Creating a react contact form with Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs

This email form will have Conditional Rendering any one above 17 will display the input for the email address, with the name attribute set to "email". For 17 less, the email input should not be rendered.

The values for the fields should be stored in the component state, under the "firstName", "age", and "email" keys. I can't make it work please help me. tq.

```
class ContactForm extends Component {
  state = {
    firstName: '',
    age: '',
    email: '',
  }


  render() {
    const {firstName, age, email} = this.state;
    if(age >= 17){
      return
      <div>
      <form className='form' onSubmit={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); this.props.onSubmit(this.state);}}>
      <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={firstName} name='firstName' />
      <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={age} name='age' />
      <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={email} name='email' />

      <button className='contact-form__submit'> Submit</button>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    } else {
      return "null"
    }
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ContactForm />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ternary operator` in your `jsx`. To do the conditional rendering, you need to use `{}` and inside the curly braces you need to use `ternary operator`. see the below example:

```
{age >= 17 ? (
            <input
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              defaultValue={email}
              name="email"
            />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
```

Here is the **complete example** from your source:

```
import React from "react";

class ContactForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    age: 16,
    email: ""
  };

  render() {
    const { firstName, age, email } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          className="form"
          onSubmit={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
          }}
        >
          <input
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            defaultValue={firstName}
            name="firstName"
          />
          <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} defaultValue={age} name="age" />
          {age >= 17 ? (
            <input
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              defaultValue={email}
              name="email"
            />
          ) : (
            ""
          )}

          <button className="contact-form__submit"> Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: Hi thank you sir but my ide prompt: Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
    in input (created by ContactForm)
    in form (created by ContactForm)
    in div (created by ContactForm)
    in ContactForm  anyway to solve this?

Comment: @Okletsgo you need to use `defaultValue` instead of `value`. I already updated my answer. pls have a look.

Comment: @Okletsgo hi you unaccepted this answer? does not it help you?

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you so much